# The responsive grid layout does not work on firefox

Tags: jquery, css, responsive-design, coffeescript

- The original view when the width greater than **960px**:
  [image]
- Too much white space on Firefox and the first grid is missing:
  [image]
- Everything works well on Chrome:
  [image]

Any suggestions on CSS syntax ?

**CSS:**

```
  .categorysection {
    margin: 0 auto;
    max-width:960px;
    &.grey {
      background: #eee;
    }
  }
  .grid-col {
    text-align: center;
    display: block;
    float: left;
    margin: 8px 6px;
  }
```

**Javascript:**

```
setContainerWidth = ->
  $('.categorysection').css 'width', 'auto'
  #reset
  windowWidth = $(document).width()
  blockWidth = $('.block').outerWidth(true)
  maxBoxPerRow = Math.floor(windowWidth / blockWidth)
  $('.categorysection').width maxBoxPerRow * blockWidth
  return

$(document).ready ->
  setContainerWidth()
  return
$(window).resize ->
  setContainerWidth()
  return
```

Comment: can you post the HTML code and the full CSS code ?